# Gradle Warning in Grails 3 build. How to resolve it?

Tags: gradle, grails, grails-3.3.x

While building my grails 3 application i am getting below warning. Can some body help regarding this.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.0-rc-4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Comment: It's telling you what's wrong and how to see the dependencies causing the problems.

Comment: Which version of Grails 3 are you using, which version of Gradle are you using and which features are the deprecation warnings related to?

Comment: I am using Grails 3.3.9.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and gradle is 4.10.2

Comment: @MichaelJ.Lee i am unable to run this command on grails build with --warning-mode all


I am doing grails clean only